# How do you properly integrate a framework/boilerplate NuGet package into your web app in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, nuget-package, razor-class-library

I have written a prototype RCL, which contains the following structure:

[image: directory structure]

Now I want to implement this logic to override the local files in an another web app, using this directory structure above as a framework, which overrides files.

For that I wrote the following .props file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   
        
    <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Areas\**\*.*"></File>
            <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Areas\**\**\*.*"></File>
        </ItemGroup>
        
        <Exec Command="xcopy /I/e/d/s/y %(File.Identity) $(ProjectDir)Pages\Shared"></Exec>
            
    </Target>

</Project>
```

.csproj has this appended:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Areas\**\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="Areas"></None>
        <None Include="Areas\**\**\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="Areas"></None>
        <None Include="build\libnamehere.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build"></None>
</ItemGroup>
```

But this appears to only copy the .cshtml.cs files, which is not good enough...

- How do I copy the .cshtml files as well?
- Is there a better method to use the _Layout.cshtml from the RCL?

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 (.NET 6) if that matters.

To summarize, I want to make one of my ASP.NET Core apps as a framework so all assets (Razor pages, JS files, C# logic, controllers etc) should be packed in a framework (which as you can see already did partly in my prototype), which can simply be referenced and it overwrites the new web app's pages in case of a conflict. Also, updates of the framework NuGet package should not break the new web app.

## P.S.

I just unzipped my NuGet package and I found no .cshtml files inside of it, only .cshtml.cs files. Why???

## Update 1

Due to a request I'm redescribing the problem. I made a regular ASP.NET Core web app, and I want to use 90% of the codebase as a boilerplate/framework for my other new projects, since that code would be the same for every project. To achieve this I created a RCL for the `.cshtml` pages mainly, but it seems NuGet **does not** pack `.cshtml` files. For making it "dynamic" I enhanced the Markup with variables from the `appsettings.json`. I need as well to have the C# logic (Program.cs, Startup.cs etc) in my new projects so I created a .NET Core library or something similar, but I haven't tried exporting it yet, I would like some guidance on that too, since Microsoft's documentation is lacking on this matter too.

Comment: Maybe I'm really not familiar with your scenario so that I can't understand your requirement. Pls forgive me for it. But could you pls describe your issue in another way? Such as your requirement is xxx, so you followed xx tutorial to realize it, but you faced xx error message or phenomenon.

Comment: @TinyWang I added an update, I hope that clarified it. I didn't manage to find any tutorials, not even proper Microsoft documentation on how to do it.

Comment: `NuGet does not pack .cshtml files` normally speaking, cshtml should be packed such as asp.net core identity library, it also contained cshtml file, so I'm afraid it may be related to boilerplate... Sorry for can't offer any effective advice on it.

Comment: Since it's a boilerplate for your future projects. Creating a project template should be an easier option.

Comment: @TinyWang I figured out that I had to make Razor Views instead of Pages to be able to include it.

Comment: @Eldar like this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template

Comment: Yeap, exactly...

Comment: thank you for your reply sir : ) @Munchkin